# How big is a nuclear reactor pressure vessel?

Tags: nuclear-engineering

With all the sudden discussion related to Nuclear power, safety, fuel, waste, etc, there's one question whose answer has so far eluded me.

How big (height and diameter) is the actual pressure vessel of a conventional BWR or PWR?  I've seen, now, about a thousand images depicting the structures of Fukushima, Chernobyl, and TMI, but none of them include units of measurement for the size of what I'm looking at.

Comment: Hi Eric - this isn't a physics question, just a measurement that you could look up. Stack Exchange sites aren't meant for [general reference](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/are-some-questions-too-simple/) questions.

Comment: Ask this on engineering.stackexchange.com .